# ListView performitemClick Nullpointer

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a list view which inflates a row layout that has buttons in it. I am trying to add functionality to the buttons when the user clicks however I have not found a way to do so. The buttons dont have functionality until the user has focus on the listview item first. In other words, the user must click the button twice for any response from the app. I have tried requesting focus on the position of the item that is on the screen in the `ArrayAdapter` that I have set on the listview. However this always leads to a null pointer. My goal is to request focus on the item that the user sees on the screen so that the buttons can have functionality whenever the user decides to click on one. Here is the code that is leading to the null pointer

```
final View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.main_feed_layout, container, false);


    // Loading products in Background Thread
    new LoadAllProducts().execute();

    // Get listview
    lv = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.listView);



    // on seleting single product
    // launching Edit Product Screen


    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            Log.i("Check", "Focused");

            usernameTV = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
            usernameTV.setOnClickListener(listener);

        }
    });`
```

At the end of the Async Task I set the adapter to the list view. then i try to perform item click which gives a null pointer when trying to find `usernameTV`.

```
  lv.performItemClick(lv.getChildAt(0), 0, lv.getChildAt(0).getId());
```

Why is this a null pointer when I programatically click the item and not a null pointer when I click the item manually?

**EDIT**
Here is the adapter code

```
 private class MyArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {


    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    private final Context context;
    private List<String> posts;
    private List<String> viewContent;
    int index = 0;

    public MyArrayAdapter(Context context, List<String> strings, List<String> content) {
        super(context, R.layout.post_layout, strings);
        this.context = context;
        this.posts = strings;
        this.viewContent = content;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();

        if(convertView == null) {

            try {

                LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.post_layout, parent, false);


                viewHolder.unameTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postUnameTv);
                viewHolder.unameTV.setText(viewContent.get(index));


                viewHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postProfPic);
                DisplayImageOptions options = initiateDisplayImageOptions();
               // viewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(listener);

                ImageLoader imageloader = ImageLoader.getInstance();

                initImageLoader(getActivity());
                imageloader.displayImage(viewContent.get(index + 1), viewHolder.image, options);


                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addToCalendarButton);
                viewHolder.addToCalendarButton.setText(viewContent.get(index + 2));

                viewHolder.eventTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postTitleTV);
                viewHolder.eventTitle.setText(viewContent.get(index + 3));

                viewHolder.eventImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.eventImage);
                imageloader.displayImage(viewContent.get(index + 4), viewHolder.eventImage, options);


                viewHolder.likesTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.likesTV);
                viewHolder.likesTV.setText("" + viewContent.get(index + 5));

                viewHolder.planToAttendTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.planToAttendTV);
                viewHolder.planToAttendTV.setText(viewContent.get(index + 6));

                viewHolder.addressTV = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.postLocationTV);
                viewHolder.addressTV.setText("" + viewContent.get(index + 7));


                index = index + 8;
            }
            catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ie)
            {
                ie.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }




        return convertView;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount()
    {
        return posts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
        return posts.get(position);
    }

     class ViewHolder {
         ImageView image;
         TextView addToCalendarButton;
         TextView eventTitle;
         ImageView eventImage;
         TextView likesTV;
         TextView planToAttendTV;
         TextView addressTV;
         TextView unameTV;

     }

}
```

Here is the layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
android:background="@drawable/fill_back"
>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/postUnameTv"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textColor="#ff518eff"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:text="Joshua" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Public"
        android:id="@+id/postProfileIcon"
        android:background="@drawable/publicicon"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="70dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postUnameTv"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="330dp"
        android:id="@+id/eventImage"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/space"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
        android:id="@+id/space" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="20px"
        android:layout_height="20px"
        android:layout_above="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:id="@+id/space2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:id="@+id/postTitleTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="117dp"
        android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:textSize="28dp"
        />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
        android:background="@drawable/details_button"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/postLocationTV"
        android:layout_below="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/locate_button"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="clip_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/space"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:id="@+id/addToCalendarButton"
        android:textSize="12dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/postLocationTV"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/add_to_cal_button"
        android:drawablePadding="5dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageButton3"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="2 hours ago"
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:textColor="#ff828084"
        android:layout_above="@+id/eventImage"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text=""
        android:id="@+id/posthelpSpace"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/space"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/postProfPic"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/postProfPic" />

</RelativeLayout>

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/likeButton"
    android:background="@drawable/like_button_unsel"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/likesTV"
    android:textColor="#ffe11100"

    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/likeButton"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likeButton"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/likeButton"
    android:gravity="center|center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.3dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/likeButton"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/divider" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:id="@+id/planToAttendTV"
    android:layout_below="@+id/likesTV"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="Yes"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView3"
    android:background="@drawable/border_circular"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/planToAttendTV"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />

<Button
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:text="No"
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/border_circular"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    android:text="Are you attending?"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/likeButton"
    android:layout_marginBottom="7dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    />
```

To clarify the behavior of the views, if I add the onclicklistener in the adapter, the result is not dynamic. Here is an example

```
//Inside adapter
                viewHolder.unameTV.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                        String t = viewHolder.unameTV.getText().toString();
                        System.out.println(t);
                    }
                });
```

The system will print out the text in the last view loaded into the listview rather than the actual listview item touched.

Comment: post the adapter code. are you indicating `usernameTV` is null??

Comment: Yes it is saying usernameTV is null

Comment: post the adapter code and the layout that you inflate in getview

Comment: why do you need to set click listener in `onListItemClick`. you can do that in adapter itself

Comment: `Here is the code that is leading to the null pointer` what is that code , where dose that code belong to?

Comment: i mean where dose your first code section belong to?

Comment: There first code is in the onCreateView of the fragment. Also, if i set the listener in the adapter, when I click on the button the response is not dynamic. I will update my question for clarification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `setOnClickListener` stuff back into the Adapter and change the `onClick` method to this:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    String t = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

This should print the text of the clicked "button". Actually, you could set up just one Listener and apply it to all of your list items and it still would work the same.

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for. It works perfectly, but why does it work? What is the difference between casting the String rather than doing it how i was doing it?

Comment: Note that in my solution the text is taken from the view that's passed into the onClick() method.